# How should I repair small tears in the kraft paper insulation caused while running a new water line?

Tags: bathroom, vapor-barrier

While installing new electrical and water drops my wire snake (and pipe deburer) poked though and tore the paper face of the insulation above my bathroom.  As this area is likely to see a lot of moisture, I' worried using masking tape, or a tape made out of a different barrier material like tyvek will provide an uneven penetrance and possible build up of water vapor in some areas.

**Is there a proper way to tape or repair the barrier such that it still lets the room 'breath' properly while protecting from condensate?**

**Is there something more cost effective than Tyvek tape? and is that even appropriate over kraft paper?**

Related: [Should I repair the kraft paper vapor barrier after remodeling work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/112876/should-i-repair-the-kraft-paper-vapor-barrier-after-remodeling-work)

Related: [Is torn kraft paper vapor retarder in the attic a problem?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20983/is-torn-kraft-paper-vapor-retarder-in-the-attic-a-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that your bathroom will have a lot of moisture in it, but if that much gets through to your insulation you're not ventilating enough. Make sure you run your bath fan regularly and for long enough, and don't overthink the repair. Use any tape that will bond well to the craft paper, except not masking or duct tape. Neither have adhesives that are suitable for the long-term.

Comment: package /box tape should be ok then?

Comment: That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the clear or brown plastic kind, by you probably mean the string reinforced paper ...which happens to be called "kraft paper tape" (of course it is LOL)!

Comment: No, I don't think you need fiber-reinforced tape. There won't ever be that much tension on it (and the paper would tear anyway).